# Bring custom control to front

Tags: c#, user-interface

I recently started to learn C# and right now I want to mess arouwnd with the Form[Design].
Right now I'm trying to `BringToFront()` custom controls each time I hover over a button (Ive got a few buttons close to each other, each time I hover over them I get a certain User Control).
This is what I've got so far:

```
private void button1_Hover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    costumControl1.BringToFront();
}

private void button1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CostumControl0.BringToFront();
}

private void button2_Hover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    costumControl2.BringToFront();
}

private void button2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CostumControl0.BringToFront();
}

private void button3_Hover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    costumControl3.BringToFront();
}

private void button3_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CostumControl0.BringToFront();
}
```

But bringing to front the user control `costumControl0` when I hover from a button to another it's not what I want.
But I don't know how to go about this.
Is it possible to just add a if statement where I check if I'm not hovering the buttons close to my current one and then display the `costumControl0`.
Or a timer is necessary to delay the display of the `costumControl0` and skip the command if I'm starting another event.
If the timer is needed, can I use one timer for all of the buttons or do I need to create one for each?

Or whats the best approach for this?

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what you are trying to achieve,

Comment: When bring to front an custom control, try to SendToBack the others. For example:

`private void button3_Hover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    costumControl3.BringToFront();
    costumControl2.SendToBack();
    costumControl1.SendToBack();
    costumControl0.SendToBack();
}`

Comment: Ive got a few buttons close to each other, if I haver over 1 I want a user control to be brought to front, and if from button 1 to hover to the next button I want the associated user control to be displayed. but with what Ive done so far, if I hover from one button to another, it displays the user control for the button leave event then the one for the second button hover event, so I want to skip the user control for leave event if I dont hover over the form or pannels

Comment: What is benefit for sending to back them? @Adnand